# CKEditor toolbar configuration not working

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckfinder

I recently started working with CKEditor, but the toolbar has functions we will not be using.

I tried copying the code from the online toolbar configuration, but the toolbar doesn't change.

my config.js file looks like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
        { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
        { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
        { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
        { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
        { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
        { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
        { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
    ];

    config.removeButtons = 'Save,NewPage,Preview,Print,Replace,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,Superscript,Subscript,Language,Anchor,Flash,PageBreak,About';
};
```

which was copies directly from the configuration tool.
After the above, I tried pasting the code into the initialization function like the following block:

```
jQuery(function() 
{   
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'message',
    {
        extraPlugins : 'stylesheetparser',
        extraPlugins : 'filebrowser',
        extraPlugins : 'popup',
        //contentsCss : '<?= base_url(); ?>css/layout.css',
         config.toolbarGroups = [
            { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
            { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
            { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
            { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
            '/',
            { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
            { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
            { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
            { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
            '/',
            { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
            { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
            { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
            { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
            { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
        ],
        config.removeButtons = 'Save,NewPage,Preview,Print,Replace,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,Superscript,Subscript,Language,Anchor,Flash,PageBreak,About'
    });

    CKFinder.setupCKEditor(editor);
});
```

I also tried simply to show one part of the toolbar like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
         config.toolbar = [
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] }
    ];

    // Toolbar groups configuration.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] }
    ];
};
```

None of the above changed anything in the toolbar, so I am not sure if I overlooked something.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure you properly define your configuration - check the [Setting CKEditor Configuration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration) article for some code examples. Some of the mistakes you are doing:

- Mixing up `config.optionName` and `optionName`.
- Declaring `extraPlugins` multiple times - you should put all extra plugins into one declaration: `config.extraPlugins = 'myplugin,anotherplugin';`

Also check some of the [CKEditor SDK samples](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/index.html) for examples - if you open any of them (like [this one](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/removeformat.html)), scroll down to the "Get Sample Source Code" section and grab the source code to copy.

Last but not least, use the JavaScript console of your browser to check for errors and clear the cache after each change!

And finally, it makes little sense to download a bloated CKEditor package and then remove plugins/buttons in your configuration - better create a custom build in [CKBuilder](http://ckeditor.com/builder).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I changed the Plugins mentioned to make the code a bit shorter...we downloaded the bloated file because not all the instances will have the same functions, so at the moment we are just trying to get this to work

Comment: managed to get it working from the source code, I put the code into the instance creator and not the config, buy think the mail problem was in the instance it must be `toolbarGroups: [` and not `toolbarGroups = [`

Answer (score 2):

```
include:
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ckeditor/config.js"></script>

<textarea id="user_message"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
var toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
    { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
    { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
    { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
    { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
    { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
    { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
    { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
];

var initEditor = function() {
  return CKEDITOR.replace( 'user_message',{
    toolbar : 'Basic',
    uiColor : '#9AB8F3',
    toolbarGroups,
   });
}
initEditor();
</script>
```

Demo
[image]

Answer (score 0):

my CKEditor config.js changes were not reflected in my toolbar until i put matched the same path as the Samples had. ex: the working sample has this path:

```
ckeditor\samples\index.html
ckeditor\config.js
```

so i made my working web page app with ckeditor this:

```
rootwebfolder/ckeditor/config.js
rootwebfolder/mywebpage.php
```

before, i had ckeditor on the same level as root, but i moved it into root.
of course i had to change the relative path statements, which are now this[and showing the other code that enables the div to show the CKEditor toolbar]:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH ='mydomain/mainfolder/rootwebfolder/ckeditor/';</script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='mydomain/mainfolder/rootwebfolder/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'></script>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='mydomain/mainfolder/rootwebfolder/ckeditor/config.js'></script>";
echo "<div id = 'divname' name = 'divname' class = 'ckeditor' style='visibility:hidden; height:415px'></div>";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>CKEDITOR.replace('divname');</script>";
```

i hope this helps someone!